# Redis Time Series Module Not Loading

Tags: redis, redistimeseries

I'm new to Redis and would like to play with the RedisTimeSeries module. Following the instructions I load the module using:

```
redis-server --loadmodule /path/to/module/redistimeseries.so
```

Obviously adjusting the path to match mine. The server starts and shows the following output:

```
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.785 # Server initialized
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.789 * <timeseries> RedisTimeSeries version 10609, git_sha=f36e5a703dc9a2487880087a34f6cb0e56d9a459
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.789 * <timeseries> Redis version found by RedisTimeSeries : 6.2.6 - oss
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.789 * <timeseries> loaded default CHUNK_SIZE_BYTES policy: 4096
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.789 * <timeseries> loaded server DUPLICATE_POLICY: block
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.789 * <timeseries> Setting default series ENCODING to: compressed
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.789 * <timeseries> Detected redis oss
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.789 * <timeseries> Enabled diskless replication
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.789 * Module 'timeseries' loaded from lib/redistimeseries.so
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.790 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.6
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.790 * RDB age 4 seconds
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.790 * RDB memory usage when created 1.02 Mb
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.790 # Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 0, keys expired: 0.
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.790 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
88537:M 02 Apr 2022 12:19:24.790 * Ready to accept connections
```

When I connect using the redis-cli I run the sample command like so:

```
TS.CREATE temperature RETENTION 60 LABELS sensor_id 2 area_id 32
```

However, I receive the following error in the CLI:

```
(error) ERR unknown command `TS.CREATE`, with args beginning with: `temperature`, `RETENTION`, `60`, `LABELS`, `sensor_id`, `2`, `area_id`, `32`,
```

No time series commands are available. Can anyone help? I'm stumped.

Comment: Is it possible that you are running more than one instance of Redis Server and connecting to the wrong one?

Comment: @LiorKogan I think you are correct. I have a an instance running and I can't actually stop it. I have to figure that out now. Thank you!